# Bootstrap Dropdown Select CSS not work with !important

Tags: html, css, select, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I'm trying to customize a little writing in the dropdown, however when I override the CSS with the! Important rule, nothing happens. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Here's what happens:

Before the selection everything is ok, but after selecting the option, the multiplier x 1.2 disappears because it is the color of the characters is white. I would like to change it but I can't.

Before selection:

[image]

After selection:

[image]

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/snake93/mfhvs6xp/132/

```
.opth {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600 !important;
  color: #2f354c  !important;
  background: #fff !important;
}

.opt {
  background: #fff !important;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 500 !important;
  color: #5f6a91 !important;
}

.filter-option {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500 !important;
  color: #5f6a91 !important;
}

.opt:hover {
  background: #F6F7F7 !important;
  color: #2f354c !important;
}

.btn {
  border-radius: 0px !important
}

.dropdown .bootstrap-select .dropdown-toggle:focus, .dropdown  .bootstrap-select>select.mobile-device:focus+.dropdown-toggle, .dropdown .btn:not(:disabled):not(.disabled) {
    outline: none !important;
 }

.dropdown.bootstrap-select.a_level {
    border: 1px solid #DCDCDE;
}

/*--Here CSS Moltiplicatore x1.2 Before Selection--*/
small.text-muted {
    color: #0d75d2!important;
}

/*--Here CSS Moltiplicatore x1.2 After Selection--*/
.bootstrap-select .dropdown-menu li.active small {
    color:  red !important;
}
```

```
<!--jQuery-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 
<!--BootStrap Select-->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.18/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.18/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<!--BootStrap-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container_level">
  <select class="a_level" id="a_level" form="bmrcalc" name="activ_level" data-show-subtext="true" data-width="100%">
    <option class="opth" value="0">Stile di vita / Attività fisica</option>
    <option class="opt" id="leggeros" name="radiosa" value="1.2" data-subtext="Moltiplicatore x 1.2">Sedentario, Smart Working, studio, pochi passi al giorno</option>
    <option class="opt" id="attivos" name="radiosa" value="1.375">Leggero, Attività fisica moderata, Corsa, fitness 1-3 Day x Week (1.375) </option>
    <option class="opt" id="allenatos" name="radiosa" value="1.55">Moderato, Operaio edile, Allenamenti intensi 4-5 Day x Week (1.55)</option>
    <option class="opt" id="Mattivos" name="radiosa" value="1.75">Attivo, Lavori pesanti, Bodybuilding, Powerlifting 6-7 Day x Week  (1.75)</option>
    <option class="opt" id="Eattivos" name="radiosa" value="1.9">Estremamente attivo, Atleta, programma di allenamento intenso 6-7 Day x Week (1.9)</option>
  </select>
</div>

<script>$('.a_level').selectpicker();</script>
```

Comment: seems you are mixing Bootstrap 4.6 javascript and the css of Bootstrap 5.1

Comment: Isn't that a good thing? Excuse the ignorance but I'm not very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add just below your bootstrap.css

```
<style>
.bootstrap-select .dropdown-menu li.active small{
  color: red !important; 
}
</style>
```

or add your custom stylesheet below bootstrap.css and put this css in it.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. But I'm curious why CSS doesn't work when placed where all the other CSS codes are. Would you be kind enough to explain it to me ?

Comment: CSS is read by the browser from top to bottom. So if you put your stylesheet or style snippet after bootstrap.css it will override previously declared  style for particular class or tag.  Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: @EmanueleDaniele I am not sure if it would cause problems. Unless you have a specific reason to combine different version I would keep the versions in sync just to prevend potential problems.